# Luhn Algorithm not working

Tags: vb.net

I've encountered a problem with a program I'm writing for school. I need to verify credit card numbers using the Luhn Algorithm, however I'm having some difficulty in getting the logic of the algorithm to work correctly. I believe I know where the problem is, but I'm unable to fix it.

I believe the problem is here:

```
For i = 0 To cardInput.Text.Length - 2 Step -2
    Dim x = (i * 2)
    If x > 9 Then
        x = x - 9
    End If
    oddTotal += x
Next

'Sum of undoubled digits
For i = 0 To cardLength - 1 Step -2
    evenTotal += i
Next

total = oddTotal + evenTotal

checkSum = total

infoOutput.Items.Add("CheckDigit: " & checkDigit)
infoOutput.Items.Add("CheckSum :" & checkSum)

'Verify that the card is valid by the Mod 10 (Lund algoritm)
If checkSum = checkDigit Or checkSum = 0 Then
    valid = True
Else
    valid = False
End If
```

If it's needed, the rest of my project can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/ccCntMtR)

My code doesn't seem to start at the last digit and take every other digit back to the beginning to be doubled. Is the Step -2 operator incorrect here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do not appear to be using the digits of the card number.

Comment: I don't understand how I'm not though if I use this code to display the selected digit, it shows fine in my listbox.

infoOutput.Items.Add(cardInput.Text.Substring(cardLength -2,1))

so my For loop should be selecting the digits and utilizing them correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here. Particularly:

If you want a loop to count backwards, you have to start at the higher index and end at the lower one. So:

```
For i = cardInput.Text.Length - 2 To 0 Step -2
```

Then, instead of using `i` directly, you should use the `i`-ith digit:

```
Dim x = Val(cardInput.Text(i))
```

The same applies to your sum of evens.

If you want to check if the last digit is zero, use the `Mod` operator:

```
valid = (checkSum Mod 10 = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realize that stepping backwards the way I was wouldn't produce the same results as reversing the string in the input, and I forgot to put the Mod 10 back in when I was playing with various other items. +1 for the answer!